# Changing a slice by passing its pointer

Tags: pointers, go, slice

I have a slice that I want to change (for example i want to remove the first element) using a function. I thought to use a pointer, but I still can't index it. What am I doing wrong?

[Playground link:](http://play.golang.org/p/V3Dhg63CCi)

```
func change(list *[]int) {
    fmt.Println(*list)
    *list = *list[1:] //This line screws everything up
}

var list = []int{1, 2, 3}

func main() {
    change(&list)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `(*list)`.

```
func change(list *[]int) {
    *list = (*list)[1:]
}
```

or a different approach that's usually more go idomatic:

```
func change(list []int) []int {
    return list[1:]
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/iCDSzeRAu6)

Comment: +1. Slices are "reference types" anyway. So you don't really gain much by passing the pointer and attempting to modify it in place.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead There are actual uses for this.  See: http://play.golang.org/p/vf1tD7_xc7 for an example that uses a slice representation to make a queue.

Comment: Thanks for the example @dyoo. I agree there are specific instances where it would make sense (like the pointer receiver for the aliased type in your example). I don't think it applies to the OP's situation though (which is what I was targeting my comment at).

Comment: @DewyBroto I am aware of that. I am not disputing what is more idiomatic :)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: "So you don't really gain much by passing the pointer and attempting to modify it in place." He is trying to change the length of the slice. He gains *everything* by passing the pointer, because you must replace a slice value to have a different length.

Comment: @newacct I am not sure I get your point.. given that the re-slice will happen either way and the reference gets updated anyway. I am saying that the overhead is minimal.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: Your comment that "Slices are "reference types" anyway." seemed to indicate that he can just pass the slice by value and not return anything, and just modify what he needs to modify through the "reference type". That is not true.

Comment: Ahhhh apologies for the confusion. I was referring to OneOfOne's second example where he just passes a reference back out. I should have been more clear.

Comment: I will attempt to rephrase my original comment. Returning a slice from the method (as OneOfOne does in his second, more idiomatic version) has very little overhead, given that slices are reference types. You're looking at the overhead of a reference copy.. which will be the native WORD size of the platform (4 or 8 bytes). Does that make more sense @newacct?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: A slice is not actually a reference type. (A reference type is just a type which consists one pointer.) A slice actually a structure of 3 values: a pointer to the array, and a length and a capacity; two of those things are not pointers, and the whole type is larger than you think.

Comment: Interesting - I was under the impression that the slice "reference" was a pointer to that structure. Thanks for the information!

Comment: @SimonWhitehead http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#SliceHeader that's how slices (and strings right under it) are represented, that's why it's cheap to move large strings around.