# main exiting to soon, due to goroutine

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to reimplement / modify the code of the second comment of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25902245/2397318).

I would like multiple go routines to pop elements from the stack (as long as the stack contains something), and another function to catch them.

[This code in playground](http://play.golang.org/p/FFgsQrI_jl)

```
func  pop(list *[]int, c chan int) {
    if len(*list) != 0 {
        result := (*list)[0]
        *list = (*list)[1:]
        fmt.Println("about to send ",result)
        c <-  result
    } else {return}
}

func receiver (c chan int){
    result := <- c
    fmt.Println("received ", result)
}

var list = []int{1, 2, 3}

func main() {

fmt.Println("Main")
c := make(chan int)
go pop (&list, c)
go pop (&list,c)
receiver(c)
fmt.Scan()
```

If I make receiver(c) a go routine, only "Main" will be printed, and the program will exit without waiting for the Scan() function. Even adding a time.Sleep(2) won't prevent the program from exiting.

Why is my program exiting without any input?

Comment: This code isn't safe because both `pop`s access a shared slice without a lock. Neither `time` nor `fmt.Scan` operate normally in the Playground but I don't know if that's the issue here.

Comment: aren't go routines supposed to be automatically safe for shared data?

Comment: Nope; shared slices, maps, etc. need to be protected by a [`sync.Mutex`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/); see http://research.swtch.com/godata for why (starting with how they're represented internally).

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. So each pop should lock the list, do its stuff and then unlock the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Scan` will not block if given zero arguments.

Note that the Playground will not block on IO even if you give it an argument, the code

```
var i int
fmt.Scan(&i)
```

Also will fail to block, if you check the `error` value it returns (the second return value), which you should, you'll see it reports `error: EOF`.

(Though that sample will block outside the Playground).

Edit: If you want to block on input without making a dummy variable, use `Scanln`, though it still will fail on the Playground.